# How to use magento Mage.php file path in wordpress plugin "mage enabler"?

Tags: magento, templates, wordpress

I am facing a small problem.I need the absolute path of Mage.php file in app folder.
I am using /pinktaff.u1163.cartikahosting.com/app/Mage.php in wordpress plugin "mage enabler"
but it is showing invalid..Can anyyou please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely `/pinktaff.u1163.cartikahosting.com` is not the full path to your document root

In magento create a blank php file in the site root and add the code below

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ? >
```

See http://www.seomad.com/SEOBlog/find-out-the-root-path-on-your-server-in-php.html

Or

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

You could also test to see if the path is correct by doing

```
 <?php
 $filename = '/pinktaff.u1163.cartikahosting.com/app/Mage.php';

 if (file_exists($filename)) {
     echo "The file $filename exists";
 } else {
     echo "The file $filename does not exist";
 }
 ?>
```